# How to get list for items within a week using PowerShell scripts?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I am writing a PowerShell script to get bookings from SharePoint 2007. Booking is made by creating an item in Calender list. The list has already been used for over 6 years. I want to write a script to send SMTP email reminders to users for bookings after 3 days. I used the following code to get the list items.

```
$service = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $uri -UseDefaultCredential
...
$xmlDoc = new-object System.Xml.XmlDocument            
$query = $xmlDoc.CreateElement("Query")            
$viewFields = $xmlDoc.CreateElement("ViewFields","Week")            
$queryOptions = $xmlDoc.CreateElement("QueryOptions")            
$query.set_InnerXml("FieldRef Name='Full Name'")
$rowLimit = "50000"
...
if($service -ne $null){
try{
    $list = ($service.GetListItems($listName, $viewName, $query, $viewFields, $rowLimit, $queryOptions, "")).data.row
    $list | export-csv "$path\list.csv"
}catch {
    Write-host "Error !! Cannot update the list.csv."
}
```

I don't want to get all the items in this 6 years every time i run the script, can i get items only in the next 3 days?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could loop through your results and use some simple math to compare the dates, using CSOM will make the logic much easier to adapt in the future.  You might be able to use the CAML query to do the date filtering too but that's not my forte:

```
Import-Module 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll'
$siteUrl = "http://Your.Site/Subsite"
$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteUrl)  
$lookupList = $ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle('Bookings')
$query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
$query.ViewXml = "<View>
    <RowLimit></RowLimit>
</View>"
$listItems = $lookupList.getItems($query)
$ctx.Load($listItems)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
foreach($item in $listItems)
{
    if([DateTime]$item["DueDate"] -lt [DateTime]::Now.Add([TimeSpan]::FromDays(3)) -and [DateTime]$item["DueDate"] -gt [DateTime]::Now)
    {
        $item["Title"]
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't find the module in C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI , I just saw BIN folder inside C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\, so I can only use CAML query to do the data filtering now?

Comment: Thank you so much, It can also applied to SharePoint 2007?

Comment: I believe the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client library only works in 2010 and 2013 and it seems I totally missed that part of your question.  Apologies.  If you can foreach your list out by item you should still be able to use the datetime scripting I showed you to find the correct events.

Comment: Never mind, I should write my conditions clearly. Many thanks for your answers.